# How to import blockchain.info wallet file?

Tags: blockchain.info

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restore locally a MyWallet backup?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/how-to-restore-locally-a-mywallet-backup)

I have blockchain.info backups, but I never test them.

How do I make sure they work?
What client should I load them into, and how?

I just want to load the wallet and do a test transfer, so the wallet doesn't have to be very fully featured etc... does Electrum support this kind of import? (I want to save on blockchain download)

Comment: I think http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3034/659 is close enough to this question to be considered a duplicate.