# How can I brute force decrypt my blockchain wallet?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I have a Blockchain wallet but am unable to decrypt my wallet and login.  I created the wallet on OSX and am trying to login on a PC but it's not working.

- What are my options to brute force this account, when I know most of the characters involved?

I'm a programmer, and can write the code, so knowing what URLs and data files I need to work with would be a help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap a brute-force wrapper around any of the [answers here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3034/78). Just write some loops that iterate on all possible passwords, and call one of the functions in the linked question to try and decrypt you wallet.

[This is what I used](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7865/78) in a similar scenario (Javascript/node.js).

Comment: This was perfect... I was able to install Node.JS on OSX and cracked it... execution time was 5 seconds.

Comment: @makerofthings7 terrific!

Comment: So does this mean someone internal at blockchain.info who has access to encrypted wallets could decrypt them by brute force in a small amount of time with limited computing power?

Comment: @Fraggle only if the password was weak to begin with. In my case, my friend who lost his wallet pass had some ideas on the password, but at the end the brute-forcing effort we did didn't work out :(

Answer (score 2):

[The wallet format can be found here](https://blockchain.info/wallet/wallet-format). [There is also a tool that does this for you](https://blockchain.info/DecryptWallet.html).