# I have lost my blockchain password and recovery phrase, how can I recover my wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I forgot my blockchain password and recovery phrase because it was saved in my phone— and i have lost my phone. 
please help me if there are any chances for recover my funds that was in blockchain

Answer (score 2):

*Please note, you are probably refering to the blockchain.info wallet service. Not the blockchain itself.*

I don't think it is possible to recover your funds if you lost your password **and** your recovery phrase.
You should have secured your recovery phrase somewhere where it can't get lost or destroyed. A phone isn't a good place for that.

Read here more for detail: https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/04/20/support-team-tips-why-your-wallet-recovery-phrase-is-so-important/

Next time, write it down on paper or store it encrypted on a cloud service where nobody other than you can access it.

You can try and contact support on blockchain.info, but I don't think they can help you as your private keys will probably be encrypted with your password and can be recovered with you recovery phrase. But as you don't have any of them, I think recovery of your funds is not possible.

For more on this, read here: https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/211205343-I-forgot-my-password-What-can-you-do-to-help-

It may be a bit salty, but learn how to deal with security and secure your passwords, use 2FA and save your recovery phrases and anything else in a secure place. This should be done for everything, not only the blockchain.info service.

COMMENT: Yes you can recover your funds without the password and wallet ID.
You can do that by requesting your wallet ID as a first step using your e-mail at this link https://login.blockchain.com/#/reminder, second step is to download the wallet.aes.json file and then its possible to brute force the password. A possible script for doing that can be found here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3037/46677